# in javascript, declare more than one variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, scope

have the following javascript code

```
// note: declaring i in this loop
for( var i=0; i<args.length; i++ ) {

   var elem = args[i];
   ...

   if( elem.attr == 'class' ) {

        // note declaring arr and i in this loop
        for( var arr=elem.val.split(' '), i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {

            element.classList.add(arr[classCt]);
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

the problem is that `i` in the second `for` loop is the same `i` as declared in the first `for` loop.

thought that the `var` construct allowed multiple variables to be declared separated by commas.

when changed `i` to `classCt` in second loop, the code worked as expected

Comment: "when changed i to classCt in second loop, the code worked as expected" - so why don't you just go with that?

Comment: Changed `i` to `classCt` where? The `i` in second for loop is indeed the same as the first because you are not initializing it again with `var`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have one scope there, so there can only be one variable with the same name. You're correct that var allows multiple variables to be declared separated by commas, but you can't declare two different variables with the same name in the same scope. You're just redeclaring a variable that already exists.

Either change it to `classCt`, or do what I do and use the variable `j` (and so on) for nested loop iterators:

```
var i, j, k, l;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right.  a variable declared in a `for` loop is visible once the loop terminates, so the scope is not restricted to the `for` loop itself.

Comment: @ccyoung That's correct, Javascript is different some other languages such as C which use block scope. It uses function scope (every function has it's own scope and there is one global scope). Here's a link to read more: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Comment: @Niko - thought could create new scope with { } block - is this not true?

Comment: @ccyoung No, that is not true. As Paul explained, only functions create new scopes in javascript. This is important to know, as this is different in a lot of other languages like Java or C. See this fiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/5Dn7w/

Comment: @Niko Technically, `with` also suffices in certain cases ... but that is not recommended :)

Answer (score 1):

You are only working within one scope, the loop does not create it's own even if you use the var keyword. You are just overwriting your i variable within your current functional scope, so for example this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
}
```

Will just print 5,6,7,8,9.

If you want to create a new scope you would have to do it using functions as is typically done in javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    })(i)
}
```

This will print 5,6,7,8,9 on their own lines 10 times.

Comment: but does using 'var' restrict the scope to the function, and if so, how to declare 2 variables within a for loop? :p